# Export in IQM format from Maya

Tags: maya, fbx

I am using Maya to make some animations, but a developer I am working with would like files in IQM format. I don't see that as an export option from Maya. Is it possible to do this? Is there a format other than IQM that Maya supports that could then be further exported to IQM?

Answer (score 1):

IQM (Inter-Quake Model) is not supported by Maya as far as I know. I have found older attempts on the internet at creating exporters from Maya to IQM, but I haven't been able to find anything more recent than 2013.

However Maya supports the fbx format, and [this repository](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm) contains a compiler that allows you to compile fbx files (among other formats) to IQM files.

It also contains IQM exporters for most blender versions and blender does support fbx, so in theory if the fbx to IQM compiler from this repo doesn't work, you should be able to export your animation as fbx to blender, and then from blender export as IQM using their exporter.

Edited for formatting

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we have been using the Maya -> FBX -> Blender -> IQM route but we find there are inconsistencies when exporting as FBX from Maya and importing into Blender. For example, one is right-handed vs left-handed, and the animation data doesn't seem to always transfer well for an as yet unknown reason, so we were hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried the compiler provided in the repository in question?
It contains an iqm.exe that can be used as a command line tool to convert the fbx file directly to an iqm file without going through blender, using the following commandline example : 
./iqm [options] output.iqm mesh.fbx anim1.fbx ... animN.fbx

Comment: The documentation seems quite good and extensive and I believe that should allow you to skip the Blender step entirely as you would just export from Maya as fbx and then use the command line tool to convert to iqm from fbx.

Comment: Will be taking a look tomorrow or this weekend, thank you. "contains an iqm.exe" if only MacOS supported .exe :)